# Nginx php-fpm on Kubernetes timeout problem

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, devops, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to define a deployment on Kubernetes about a web application.

As you can see in follow deployment manifest there is a pod with two containers inside:

- Nginx
- php-fpm

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: app
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sylius-php-fpm
        image: php-fpm:v4
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          subPath: default.conf
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          subPath: default.conf
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
```

I have defined a volume with follow configMap about nginx configuration:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  default.conf: |
        server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name _;
            root        /srv/app/public;

            location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
            }

            location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
                internal;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
              return 404;
            }

            client_max_body_size 6m;

            error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        }
```

Also i use ksync to sync source code between development environment and Kubernetes cluster.
So i have exposed nginx on 80 port and cgi on 9000 port defining services in this way:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app
  type: ClusterIP 
------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-fpm
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: app
  type: ClusterIP
```

and define port-forward to access to web server from local environment like so:

```
kubectl port-forward web-68b788956d-98zcs 80:80
```

I don't understand why when i try to visit 127.0.0.1 i receive a timeout occured error

It seems that nginx doesn't communicate with php-fpm container

I say that because if i try to see an html file inside root path server it works fine, but index.php in the same directory doesn't works.

Also when i try to ping php-fpm from nginx container

How can i do to solve my problem?
Anyone can help me please?

Thank you in advance to everyone and sorry for long post.

Comment: Did I get you right here: You can NOT ping the php-fpm endpoint from inside your NGINX container? I hade similar problems and thats why I am using NGINX Unit for PHP now. Much easier to setup. https://github.com/tippexs/unitwp

Comment: Could you share your nginx container logs?

Comment: KFC_ I don't see nothing on nginx logs. 
Trying to wget localhost on nginx container, after some time (about 30 sec) i see this message 
`Connecting to localhost (127.0.0.1:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out`
this happen only because server try to serve index.php file and i think that container doesn't see php-fpm container